# Swift 3, generics, compile error

Tags: swift3

This code not compile. Why?

```
class A {}

class B<TypeA: A> {}

class C<TypeA:A, TypeB:B<TypeA>> {
    var b: TypeB?
}
```

You may check that on https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiler bug.
Create task on http://bugs.swift.org